# OrientDB: What are Class Properties used for ?

Tags: orientdb

I'm new to OrientDB and I understood that classes can have properties and in this case they actually act as tables in relational databases. However, I found out that even if I define properties for a class, it still doesn't guarantee that a document created from this class has a value for all its properties.

For example: 
Here, I define a class 'Person' with a property 'name', and I still insert a new document to this class although it doesn't have a value for this property.
If so, what is the purpose of properties and how can I make sure that documents that do NOT include a value for a certain property will not be inserted into the class?

> orientdb {db=GratefulDeadConcerts}> create class person
>
> Class created successfully. Total classes in database now: 17.
>
> orientdb {db=GratefulDeadConcerts}> create property person.name string
>
> Property created successfully with id=1.
>
> orientdb {db=GratefulDeadConcerts}> insert into person content
>   {"phone":"1234"}
>
> Inserted record 'person#66:0{phone:1234} v1' in 0.000000 sec(s).
>
> orientdb {db=GratefulDeadConcerts}> select from person
>
> +----+-----+------+-----+
>   |#   |@RID |@CLASS|phone|
>   +----+-----+------+-----+ 
>   |0   |#66:0|person|1234 |
>   +----+-----+------+-----+

Answer (score 2):

In OrientDB you can work in schema-less, schema-hybrid or schema-full.
You can define properties and you can define constraints on each property:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Create-Property.html

At the same time you can define indexes on property:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Indexes.html

For example, if you want that a property has unique values over the entire class (a primary key), just define a unique index:

CREATE INDEX Person.name ON Person (name) UNIQUE

hope this help